# Angularjs directive creates watches

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have an angular directive that creates a numeric spinner (`<input type="number>`) which one can pass in a minimum and maximum to.

However I have noticed that angular will create a watch for the `min` and `max` values passed to the directive, as well as where `min` and `max` are used in the template. This is a problem as in reality there will be a number more paramaters that can be passed in, and this is inside of a large `ng-repeat`.

The directive is as follows:

```
.directive('inputNumber', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            min: '@',
            max: '@'
        },
        template: '<input type="number" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" ng-model="value"/>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.value = parseFloat($scope.min);
        }
    }
})
```

And is used as so:

```
<input-number data-min="{{min}}" data-max="{{max}}"></input-number>
```

I have no need for the watches as the values will never change once they are set, so I can use one-time bindings within my template:

```
template: '<input type="number" min="{{::min}}" max="{{::max}}" ng-model="value"/>'
```

One-time binding can also be used on the directive itself.

However this means all developers will need this taught to them so that they know to use this approach. Therefore is there anyway to avoid the one-time binding when the directive is used, but still get the benefit of it?

[JSFiddle without one-time bindings](https://jsfiddle.net/4LcxuL5w/1/)

[JSFiddle **with** one-time bindings](https://jsfiddle.net/9c04tvus/1/)

### Update

It also seems that if you use a two-way binding then angular creates two watches, one for each end of the binding. Is where any way to get around this either?

Comment: How about settings the attributes programically:  


    template: '<input type="number" ng-model="value"/>',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.value = parseFloat($scope.min);
        $element.attr('min',$scope.min).attr('max',$scope.max)
    }

Comment: That does eliminate the watch from the directive template, but this could be done already with one-time binding. However I really need to eliminate the watch caused by using the directive.

Comment: Well, I think these are your two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually get the interpolated values once with `$parse` or `scope.$eval`, and use one-time binding (`{{::var}}`) inside the template:

```
.directive('inputNumber', function ($parse) {
   scope: {},
   template: '<input type="number" min="{{::min}}" max="{{::max}}" ng-model="value"/>',
   link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
     $scope.min = $parse($attrs.min)($scope.$parent);
     $scope.max = $parse($attrs.max)($scope.$parent);
     // etc...
   }
}
```

The usage would be:

```
<input-number data-min="min" data-max="max"></input-number>
```