# one-time binding to custom attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, binding

I'm using angular one-time binding for a custom directive based on certain attribute (`relative`)

This is my directive:

```
app.directive('relative', ['$timeout', '$filter', '$compile', function ($timeout, $filter, $compile) {
    var dateFilter = $filter('date');

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            datetime: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            var timeout;

            $scope.$watch('datetime', function (dateString) {
                $timeout.cancel(timeout);

                var date = (dateString || $element.text()) * 1000;
                if (!date) return;
                date = new Date(date);
                if (!date) return;

                function update() {
                    var reference = new Date();
                    $element.text(prettyDate(date));

                    //Calculate the next update
                    var diff = Math.abs(date - reference) / 1000;
                    var delta;
                    if (diff < 45) {
                        delta = 45 - diff;
                    } else if (diff < 90) {
                        delta = 90 - diff;
                    } else if (diff < 45 * 60) {
                        delta = 60 - (diff + 30e3) % 60;
                    } else {
                        delta = 3660 - diff % 3600;
                    }

                    timeout = $timeout(update, delta * 1000);
                }

                update();    

                $element.on('$destroy', function () {
                    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And this is how I use it:

```
 <time relative datetime="{{ notice.date }}"></time>
```

Or:

```
 <time relative datetime="{{ ::notice.date }}"></time>
```

The question is: how can I avoid creating a watch for datetime attribute when one-time binding is used, given that value will never change? Does angular do it automatically?

Comment: You create one watcher yourself and can remove it yourself after the value has been bound in case of one-time binding. `datetime: '@'` is pointless if you have your own watcher anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194100/1865844) is the solution you are looking for.

You can pick up the datetime value through attribute rather than accepting it through your scope object. This will avoid creation of unwanted watch. Anyways you don't expect that value to get changed so it will really not impact much.

Comment: But I'm not always using one-time binding for that attribute, I just showed the special case when that value doesn't change. I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the `$watch` to trigger the `update` function initially. You should avoid using watchers, and opt to refactor the initialization outside of the watcher. In order to avoid the initial trigger when angular adds a watched variable to the watch list you can do this ([source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)):

```
$scope.$watch('datetime', function (dateString, oldDateString) {
    // notice the use of strict equality operator '==='
    // angular ensures this will only be true on the initialization of the watcher
    if (dateString === oldDateString) {
        return;
    }
});
```

By using `<time relative datetime="{{ ::notice.date }}"></time>` angular will not trigger the watcher after the onetime binding.

After inspecting the `$$watchers` property on the `Scope` object, I can't see any difference to the number of watchers registered with or without a `$watch`, which I suspect batarang is using.

In response to your question, I believe that it's not possible to avoid creating a watcher with one-time binding.

Comment: But tools like angular batarang show that there is a watch active, even if not triggered because of the onetime binding.

Comment: Once you declare a watcher, angular adds it to the watchers. A clunky way of solving this would be to add another attribute and check if it exists and then add the watcher.

Comment: @JavierMarín after checking what I see you maybe getting watchers because of the binding from parent into child scope, i.e. `scope: { datetime: '@' }` so batarang may be showing you something you're not expecting. I'll edit my response to say that you can't stop initialization of a watcher.

Comment: I ended up adding another attribute and when it exists, I don't call $watch